# How to change the UILabel text color according to the background image color?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

I want to change the label text color according to the background image color. The background image is on a `UIScrollView`, and the `UILabel` is on top of that. When the scroll view is scrolling, the label color should be changed based upon what the background image color is.

Basically, something like if the label was on the yellow part of the image, it would be black, and if it was on the blue part of the image, it would be white.

See the image below:

[image: if the label was on the yellow part of the image, it would be black, and if it was on the blue part of the image, it would be white]

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: If you did that, wouldn't you lose the ability to read the label?

Comment: You need to clarify what you want. It seems from your post that you want the text color to be the same as the background color, which would make it disappear. I'm assuming that's not what you want.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify. The question can be read as: how do I make the text color the same as that of the background, which in the best case would make the text invisible! If that's what you are after, then just hide the label in the first place, or go the roundabout way of doing the same as suggested by one of the answers below. However if your question is about choosing the text color such that the text can be read comfortably over varying backgrounds, then it is an entirely different question. Research color spaces, and find a "opposite" color to the background. Wikipedia is your friend:)

Comment: if u do so then i think your label can not be visible

Comment: Hopefully my edit will help make the question more clear

Answer (score 1):

First create an `UIView` let say it's `hiddenView` with the same size as the `contentsize` of your `scorllview` and set the background color from you `image` that you set background of your `scrollview` but you don't need to add this view to any where.

Implement `scrollViewDidScroll` method

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
 {
     CGRect visibleRect;
     visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
     visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size;

     float theScale = 1.0 / scale;
     visibleRect.origin.x *= theScale;
     visibleRect.origin.y *= theScale;
     visibleRect.size.width *= theScale;
     visibleRect.size.height *= theScale;

     CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect((CGImageRef)hiddenView.layer.contents, visibleRect);
     UIImage *BackImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
     [YourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:BackImage];
 }
```

Try this, hopefully it'll fulfill your requirement.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Updated to Swift 3 Below:  

```var visibleRect = CGRect()
visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset
visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size

let scale: CGFloat = 1.0 / UIScreen.main.scale
visibleRect.origin.x *= scale
visibleRect.origin.y *= scale
visibleRect.size.width *= scale
visibleRect.size.height *= scale

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: contentView.bounds.size)
let image = renderer.image { _ in
     view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}

label.textColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)```